# JavaScript: cloneNode vs importNode

Tags: javascript, dom, clonenode

I noticed in some code samples to seemingly different ways to clone a DOM node and append it to an existing element:

```
element.appendChild(something.cloneNode(true));
element.appendChild(document.importNode(something, true));
```

Both have the effect of copying a node. The second version seems more verbose, and implies that the copy is actually somewhere concrete first, though it still needs to find a proper home. However, it is used by MDN and a few other as an illustration of using the `template` tag. Elsewhere they go for the simpler `clodeNode` option.

The question is: what is the benefit to using `importNode` over `cloneNode`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode#Notes leads to https://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html#ownerdoc. When you copy an element from a different DOM, you should use `importNode`, to avoid different DOM behaviors issues.

Comment: @Kaiido How does this differ from `cloneNode`?

Comment: only referring on my understanding of previous links, with `importNode`, the new document will make the cloned node his, (sharing its DOM methods and possibly things like NameSpaces etc.), while with `externalDocument.cloneNode()`, the cloned node will still have `externalDocument`'s APIs.

Comment: In DOM3 and earlier, importNode was for copying nodes from other documents, cloneNode for copying within the same document. But browsers don't enforce that, so in the [latest DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) cloneNode can be used to copy from a different document. When using DOM in other contexts, stick with the DOM3 rules.

Comment: @Alohci If I understand that correctly, the idea _was_ that both will clone a node from the same document, but `importNode` will also clone from a different document. However, now I can choose either? Would you turn that into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In DOM3 and earlier, importNode was for copying nodes from other documents, cloneNode for copying within the same document. But browsers don't enforce that, so in the latest [DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org) cloneNode can be used to copy from a different document. When using DOM in other contexts, stick with the DOM3 rules.