# What to use instead of cloneNode() in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, clonenode

The following JavaScript function is intended to open a new HTML page and to copy a div's content to it (the actual task is, of course, more complex than copying):

```
function copydiv(srcid) {
    var w = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
    var otherdoc = w.document;
    otherdoc.write('<html><body>');
    otherdoc.write('</body></html>');
    otherdoc.close();
    var srcdiv = document.getElementById(srcid);
    var otherbody = otherdoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    // (A) var dstdiv = otherdoc.createElement('div');
    // (A) otherbody.appendChild(dstdiv);
    // (A) dstdiv.innerHTML = srcdiv.innerHTML;
    // (B) otherbody.appendChild(srcdiv.cloneNode(true));
    // (C) otherbody.appendChild(otherdoc.importNode(srcdiv, true));
}
```

The code parts marked (A) / (B) / (C) are alternatives; all three work in Firefox. However, only (A) works in Internet Explorer (11.49). The others throw the following exceptions:

- (B) HierarchyRequestError
- (C) Interface not supported

Although question [JavaScript: cloneNode vs importNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167537/javascript-clonenode-vs-importnode) suggests that “browsers don't enforce” the difference between `cloneNode` and `importNode` I would understand the need for the latter, as the source and destination nodes belong to different documents (which Firefox does not care about). But why doesn't Internet Explorer support `importNode`, given that it does not allow `cloneNode` in this case? Copying `innerHTML` seems an awkward way of cloning a node. Is there a better alternative to `importNode` for Internet Explorer? (Ideally it would be browser-independent.)

Comment: "_why doesn't Internet Explorer support `importNode`_". Simply because IE was born a long time before `importNode` was invented. However, it is supported in IE9+, hence you're probably running the page in a downgraded document mode.

Comment: Thanks, @Teemu. The „compatibility view“ list in my IE is empty, and my test server is in my local area network but I will check for other ways of specifying „a downgraded document mode“ (`<!DOCTYPE>` issue?). Still the case suggests that using `importNode` might exclude a substantial part of WWW users from using the page, so I may fall back to the `innerHTML` solution.

Comment: After playing with `<DOCTYPE>` and F12 developer tools I fail to see why my page should run in a downgraded document mode. F12 consistently shows „Edge (Standard),“ and setting it to „10“ or „9“ does not change anything; `importNode()` keeps throwing `Error--Interface not supported`. Setting it to „8“ produces „`TypeError--The object does not support the property or method "importNode"`;“ so there is indeed a difference starting with version 9. Not that it is of much use.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you can use:

```
const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
```

But if you had cross references issues, use better this approach, wich converts to text first, and then again to DOM node:

```
const clone = new DOMParser().parseFromString(node.outerHTML, "text/html").body.firstChild;
```